# JFrame button click NullPointerException

Tags: java, error-handling, nullpointerexception, awt

I keep getting the following error when I click on a button from a welcome JFrame to load into my main Frame :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at SRC_Main.actionPerformed(SRC_Main.java:291)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
```

On my main `frame` I have a `next` and `previous` buttons and I'm using and array of objects to populate an array to store Records of `Cars`.
**But** if i run the Main Jframe on its own the `next` and `prev` button works so there is no cannot file textfile and so on.

Why is it not "Initializing" ?
Here is the code for the main

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.color.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import  sun.audio.*;    //import the sun.audio package
import  java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
//end imports

public class SRC_Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
    private JPanel pnlQuote=new JPanel();
    private JButton btnNext=new JButton(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/GordonS/Desktop/SRC_MOTORS/src/Next-48.png"));
    private JButton btnPrevious=new JButton(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/GordonS/Desktop/SRC_MOTORS/src/Previous-48.png"));
    private JButton btnSound=new JButton(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\GordonS\\Desktop\\SRC_MOTORS\\src\\Sound-32.png"));
    private JButton btnQuoteDoc=new JButton(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/GordonS/Desktop/SRC_MOTORS/src/Document-32.png"));
    private JButton btnCalculate=new JButton(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/GordonS/Desktop/SRC_MOTORS/src/Calculator-32.png"));
    private JButton btnPrintQuote=new JButton(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/GordonS/Desktop/SRC_MOTORS/src/Print-32.png"));
    //Labels for Display
    private JLabel CarImage=new JLabel();
    private JLabel lblTitle=new JLabel("SRC_MOTORS");
    private JLabel lblSlogan=new JLabel("We search and strike for the best prices,so you don't have to!");
    private JLabel lblLikes = new JLabel();
    private JLabel lblDLikes = new JLabel();

    private JLabel quote=new JLabel("Interested in owning? Let us create a Quote for you");
    //***add Finance labels here

    //TextFields and Areas
    private JTextArea txtCarDetails = new JTextArea();

    //for MenuBar
    private JMenuBar menuB=new JMenuBar();
    private JMenu File = new JMenu("File");
    private JMenu Edit = new JMenu("Edit");
    private JMenu Home = new JMenu("Home");
    private JMenu Exit = new JMenu("Exit");
    private JMenu Quote = new JMenu("Develope Quote");
    private JMenu Print = new JMenu("Print");
    //====================================================
    private String [] carPathImg=
        {
            "C:/Users/GordonS/Desktop/SRC_MOTORS/src/RS3.jpg","C:/Users/GordonS/Desktop/SRC_MOTORS/src/FocusSTedit.jpg",
            "C:/Users/GordonS/Desktop/SRC_MOTORS/src/GR7.jpg","C:/Users/GordonS/Desktop/SRC_MOTORS/src/A45M.jpg",
            "C:/Users/GordonS/Desktop/SRC_MOTORS/src/SCIRR.jpg","C:/Users/GordonS/Desktop/SRC_MOTORS/src/M313.jpg"
        };

    //========ScannerOBJ========
    private Scanner x;
    //==========================================================================================================
    private CarsRec[] arrMasterRec;
    private static int i=0;//counter for record numbers
    private static int counter=0;
    private String RecordContent="";

    //components for finance panel
    private JLabel lblInstr=new JLabel("    Car Price:");
    private JLabel lblDepo=new JLabel("Initial Deposit:");
    private JLabel lblInt=new JLabel("Interest rate:");
    private JLabel lblyears=new JLabel("Payment Period:");
    private JLabel lblTotalcalc=new JLabel("Calculate All Info");


    private JTextField txtPrice=new JTextField(10);
    private JLabel lblTotalIntEar=new JLabel();
    private JLabel lblTotalCarAmt=new JLabel();
    private JLabel lblMonthly=new JLabel();
    private JLabel lblPaymentP=new JLabel();
    private JLabel lblPrice=new JLabel();

    private JTextField txtInitial=new JTextField("0", 10);
    private JComboBox cmbInterest =new JComboBox(new String[]{"5%","6%","7%","8%","9%"});
    private JComboBox cmbPeriod=new JComboBox(new String[]{"12","24","36","48","60"});
    private JCheckBox chkTotPayDetail=new JCheckBox();

    private JButton btnCalc=new JButton("Process");
    private JButton btnView=new JButton("View Full Quote");
    private JButton btnPrint=new JButton("Print");
    private JButton btnEmail=new JButton("Email");
    private JButton btnCancel=new JButton("Cancel Quote");

    private String Emailcont;
    private String EmailOwner;
    //==========================================================================================================
    //Constructor
    public SRC_Main() 
    {
        super("SRC_MotorsMain");
        setSize(1015,741);
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);

        pnl.setLayout(null);
        pnlQuote.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,5,20,20));
        pnl.setSize(1015,741);
        pnl.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        //Look and Feel of Components
        lblTitle.setForeground(Color.RED);
        lblTitle.setFont(new Font("Blade Runner Movie Font",0,38));

        quote.setFont(new Font("Tahoma",1,13));
        quote.setForeground(Color.RED);

        lblSlogan.setFont(new Font("Berlin Sans FB Demi",2,14));
        lblSlogan.setForeground(Color.RED);

        lblLikes.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lblDLikes.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        Border border2 = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED,5);
        pnl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border2, 
                    BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)));


        //Editing TXTFIELDS****************************************

        txtCarDetails.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0)), "Vehicle_Information", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Copperplate Gothic Light", 3, 14), new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255)));
        txtCarDetails.setRows(20);
        txtCarDetails.setColumns(25);
        txtCarDetails.setEditable(false);
        txtCarDetails.setFont(new Font("Berlin Sans FB Demi",2,13));
        txtCarDetails.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        txtCarDetails.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        txtCarDetails.setText("Use the directional"+"\n"+" buttons to navigate through the records");
        CarImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\GordonS\\Desktop\\SRC_MOTORS\\src\\car_front_intro"));
        //==========================================================
        CarImage.setSize(360,420);

        //Part that adds MenuBars and items
         File.add(Home);
         File.add(Exit); 
         Edit.add(Quote);
         Edit.add(Print);
         menuB.add(File);
         menuB.add(Edit);
         setJMenuBar(menuB);

         //:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

         //******Layouts of Components*********************************************************************
         pnl.add(lblTitle);
         lblTitle.setBounds(320, 0, 290, 70);

         pnl.add(lblSlogan);
         lblSlogan.setBounds(270, 60, 390, 15);

         pnl.add(CarImage);
         CarImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\GordonS\\Desktop\\SRC_MOTORS\\src\\car_front_intro.png"));
         CarImage.setBounds(30, 80, 360, 410);

         pnl.add(txtCarDetails);
         txtCarDetails.setBounds(520, 90, 420, 185);

         pnl.add(quote);
         quote.setBounds(510, 360, 360, 30);

         pnl.add(btnQuoteDoc);
         btnQuoteDoc.setBounds(870, 350, 30, 40);

         pnl.add(btnSound);
         btnSound.setBounds(715, 280, 40, 40);
         btnPrevious.setEnabled(false);

         pnl.add(btnNext);
         btnNext.setBounds(870, 280, 70, 40);

         pnl.add(btnPrevious);
         btnPrevious.setBounds(520, 280, 70, 40);
         btnPrevious.setEnabled(false);

         //ADD EXTRA PANEL FOR FINANCE
         pnlQuote.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
         chkTotPayDetail.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
         pnlQuote.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0)), "SRC_FINANCE", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Copperplate Gothic Light", 3, 14), new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255)));

         pnlQuote.add(lblInstr);
         pnlQuote.add(lblDepo);
         pnlQuote.add(lblInt);
         pnlQuote.add(lblyears);
         pnlQuote.add(lblTotalcalc);
         pnlQuote.add(txtPrice);
         txtPrice.setEditable(false);
         pnlQuote.add(txtInitial);
         pnlQuote.add(cmbInterest);
         pnlQuote.add(cmbPeriod);
         pnlQuote.add(chkTotPayDetail);
        // pnlQuote.add(new JLabel("Details: "));
         pnlQuote.add(lblPrice);
         pnlQuote.add(lblTotalIntEar);
         pnlQuote.add(lblTotalCarAmt);
         pnlQuote.add(lblMonthly);
         pnlQuote.add(lblPaymentP);
         pnlQuote.add(btnCalc);
         pnlQuote.add(btnView);
         pnlQuote.add(btnPrint);
         pnlQuote.add(btnEmail);
         pnlQuote.add(btnCancel);
         pnl.add(pnlQuote);
         pnlQuote.setBounds(490,400, 450, 270);
         pnlQuote.setVisible(false);

         //ActionListeners For Buttons
         btnNext.addActionListener(this);
         btnPrevious.addActionListener(this);
         btnQuoteDoc.addActionListener(this);

         btnView.addActionListener(this);
         btnCalc.addActionListener(this);
         btnPrint.addActionListener(this);
         btnEmail.addActionListener(this);
         btnCancel.addActionListener(this);


         i=0;
         add(pnl);
         validate();

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to SRC_MOTORS"+"\n"+"Our mission is to find the best Performance Modded Cars at the lowest of prices!"+"\n"+"Visit our ABOUT page for more information");
         //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "");
    }
    //********************************************END_OF_GUI*****************************************************
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//==(1)Open Textfile=====================================
    public void OpenFile()
    {
        try
        {
            x=new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/GordonS/Desktop/SRC_MOTORS/src/CarRecords.txt"));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot Find CarRecords! "+e);
        }
    }
//==(2)ReadTextFile======================================
    public CarsRec[] ReadFile()
    {
        int count=0;
        //Array of Objects of The Car Records class-set to Max 100 
        CarsRec [] arrRec=new CarsRec[100];

        while(x.hasNext())
        {
            String line=x.nextLine();
            String arr[]=line.split("#");
            arrRec[count]=new CarsRec(arr[0],arr[1],arr[2],arr[3],arr[4],arr[5],arr[6],arr[7],arr[8],arr[9],arr[10],arr[11]);
            count ++;
        }//close while
        x.close();//close Scanner use in txt
        return arrRec;
    }
//==(3)Preparing ArrObj for use in this class-GETMETHODS
    public void setCarRecs(CarsRec[] arr)
    {
        arrMasterRec=arr;
    }
//************************************************End TextFiles Part**********************************************************
//============================================================================================================================
    //BUTTONS ACTION AND PROCESSES
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        //==========NEXT==========
        if(e.getSource()==btnNext)
        {
            btnPrevious.setEnabled(true);
            btnSound.setEnabled(true);

            if(i<carPathImg.length)
            {
                RecordContent="CarID: "+arrMasterRec[i].getCarID()+"\n"+"Car Name: "+arrMasterRec[i].getName()+"\n"+"Engine Consumption: "+arrMasterRec[i].getLiter()
                        +"\n"+"Transmission Type: "+arrMasterRec[i].getTrans()+"\n"+"Year of model: "+arrMasterRec[i].getYear()+"\n"+"Mileage: "+arrMasterRec[i].getMileage()
                        +"\n"+"Modification Company: "+arrMasterRec[i].getModComp()+"\n"+"Software Stage Modded: "+arrMasterRec[i].getModStage()+"\n"+
                        "Power and Performance output: "+arrMasterRec[i].getPerformance()+"\n"+"Price: "+"R"+arrMasterRec[i].getPrice()+"\n"+"Owner Name: "+arrMasterRec[i].getCusName();

                txtCarDetails.setText(RecordContent);
                CarImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(carPathImg[i]));

                txtPrice.setText("R "+arrMasterRec[i].getPrice()+" "+i);
                Emailcont=RecordContent;
                EmailOwner=arrMasterRec[i].getCusEmail();
                i++;

            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Reached end of records!");
                btnNext.setEnabled(false);
            }   
        }
        //==========================================================================================================    

        //========PREVIOUS=========
        if(e.getSource()==btnPrevious)
        {
            btnNext.setEnabled(true);
            if(i>0)
            {
            i--;
            RecordContent="CarID: "+arrMasterRec[i].getCarID()+"\n"+"Car Name: "+arrMasterRec[i].getName()+"\n"+"Engine Consumption: "+arrMasterRec[i].getLiter()
                    +"\n"+"Transmission Type: "+arrMasterRec[i].getTrans()+"\n"+"Year of model: "+arrMasterRec[i].getYear()+"\n"+"Mileage: "+arrMasterRec[i].getMileage()
                    +"\n"+"Modification Company: "+arrMasterRec[i].getModComp()+"\n"+"Software Stage Modded: "+arrMasterRec[i].getModStage()+"\n"+
                    "Power and Performance output: "+arrMasterRec[i].getPerformance()+"\n"+"Price: "+"R"+arrMasterRec[i].getPrice()+"\n"+"Owner Name: "+arrMasterRec[i].getCusName();

            txtCarDetails.setText(RecordContent);
            CarImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(carPathImg[i]));
            txtPrice.setText("R "+arrMasterRec[i].getPrice()+" "+i);
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You are currently viewing the First Record!");
                btnPrevious.setEnabled(false);
                btnSound.setEnabled(false);
            }

        }
        //===========================================================================================================


        if(e.getSource()==btnQuoteDoc)
        {
            pnlQuote.setVisible(true);
            try{
                // open the sound file as a Java input stream
                String gongFile = "C:\\Users\\GordonS\\Desktop\\SRC_MOTORS\\src\\VWSCIRROCO.aiff";
                InputStream in = new FileInputStream(gongFile);

                // create an audiostream from the inputstream
                AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(in);

                // play the audio clip with the audioplayer class
                AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
            }
        }

        if(e.getSource()==btnCalc)
        {
            double deposit=0;
            deposit=Double.parseDouble(txtInitial.getText());
            double intRate=0;
            int period=0;
            double Total=0;
            double AccumulatedAmount=0;
            double monthlyIn=0;
            double Carprice=Double.parseDouble(arrMasterRec[i].getPrice());

            //Setting intRate value
            if(cmbInterest.getSelectedIndex()==0)
            {
                intRate=(5/100);
            }
            else if(cmbInterest.getSelectedIndex()==1)
            {
                intRate=(8/100);
            }
            else if(cmbInterest.getSelectedIndex()==2)
            {
                intRate=(10/100);
            }
            else if(cmbInterest.getSelectedIndex()==3)
            {
                intRate=(12/100);
            }
            else if(cmbInterest.getSelectedIndex()==4)
            {
                intRate=(15/100);
            }
            //END
            //Setting period value
            if(cmbPeriod.getSelectedIndex()==0)
            {
                period=1;
            }
            else if(cmbPeriod.getSelectedIndex()==1)
            {
                period=2;
            }
            else if(cmbPeriod.getSelectedIndex()==2)
            {
                period=3;
            }
            else if(cmbPeriod.getSelectedIndex()==3)
            {
                period=4;
            }
            else if(cmbPeriod.getSelectedIndex()==4)
            {
                period=5;
            }
            //=======================================================

            AccumulatedAmount= (Carprice-deposit)*(1+(intRate*(period)));
            Total=AccumulatedAmount+Carprice;
            monthlyIn=Total/(period*12);

            lblPrice.setText("R "+Carprice);
            lblTotalCarAmt.setText("R "+Total);
            lblTotalIntEar.setText("R "+AccumulatedAmount);
            lblMonthly.setText("R "+Math.round(monthlyIn));
            lblPaymentP.setText(period+" months");

            QuoteLayout="\n"+"Initial Price: "+Carprice+"\n"+"Total Amount: "+Total+"\n"+"Interest Earned: "+AccumulatedAmount+
                    "\n"+"Monthly Installments: "+monthlyIn+"\n"+"Period: "+period+" Months";
        }
        //==================MENU_OPTIONS====================
        if(e.getSource()==Exit)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        //==================================================
        if(e.getSource()==btnEmail)
        {
            //******************************************
            String name=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your Name: ");
             final String username="src.motortp@gmail.com";
              final String password="SRC_MOTORS123";
              String cont="Mr/Mrs "+name+"\n"+"is interested in purchasing the following advertised Vehicle :";
                System.out.println(cont);     

              Properties props= new Properties();
              props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
              props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
              props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
              props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

              Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator()
                      {
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
                        {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                        }
                      });
              try
              {
                  Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                  message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("src.motortp@gmail.com"));
                  message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse("agordon03@gmail.com"));
                  message.setSubject("SRC_MOTORS on behalf of "+name);
                  message.setContent(cont+"\n"+Emailcont,"text/html");
                  Transport.send(message);
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Message Sent!");
                  System.out.println("This email is successful");
              }
              catch(MessagingException err)
              {
                  throw new RuntimeException(err);
              }

            //******************************************
        }


    }
    //================================================================================================================
    private String QuoteLayout="";
    //================================================================================================================
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //new SRC_Main();
        SRC_Main read =new SRC_Main();
        read.OpenFile();
        CarsRec[] arrMRecords=read.ReadFile();
        read.setCarRecs(arrMRecords);   
    }

}
```

Code for the WelcomeSrc

```
   import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.color.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class WelcomeSRC extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
private JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
private JPanel pnl2 = new JPanel();
private JLabel bckPic=new JLabel();
private JProgressBar progressBar=new JProgressBar();
private JButton btnLoad=new JButton();

private JButton btnProceed=new JButton("Proceed to records...");
private Timer timer;
final static int interval=100;
int i;

    public WelcomeSRC()
    {
        super("SRC_MOTORS Home");
        setSize(1367,677);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

         btnLoad.setFont(new Font("Berlin Sans FB Demi",2,26));
         btnLoad.setForeground(Color.RED);
         progressBar.setBackground(Color.white);
         progressBar.setForeground(Color.red);
         progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
         progressBar.setValue(0);

         btnLoad.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/GordonS/Desktop/SRC_MOTORS/src/loading.gif"));
         btnProceed.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/GordonS/Desktop/SRC_MOTORS/src/Login_in-32.png"));
        // btnLoad.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/GordonS/Desktop/SRC_MOTORS/src/25.gif"));
         pnl2.setOpaque(false);
         pnl2.setLayout(null);
         pnl2.setBounds(430, 410, 420, 170);

         pnl2.add(progressBar);
         progressBar.setBounds(60, 10, 289, 20);

         pnl2.add(btnLoad);
         btnLoad.setBounds(180, 50, 40, 40);

        // pnl2.add(lblProceed);
        // lblProceed.setBounds(110, 130, 220, 40);

        progressBar.setVisible(false);
        pnl.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        pnl.setSize(1367,677);
        bckPic.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/GordonS/Desktop/SRC_MOTORS/src/back.png"));

        pnl.add(bckPic,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        getContentPane().add(pnl2);
        add(pnl);
        validate();
        i=0;
        btnProceed.addActionListener(this);
        btnLoad.addActionListener(this);
        //==================================================
        timer = new Timer(interval, new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev)
            {
                if(i==100)
                {
                    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                    timer.stop();
                //  progressBar.setValue(0);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Contents Successfully Loaded!");
                    btnLoad.hide();
                    pnl2.add(btnProceed);
                    btnProceed.setBounds(180, 50, 40, 40);
                }
                i=i+1;
                progressBar.setValue(i);
            }
        });
        //==================================================



        }
    //==================================================================
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource()==btnLoad)
        {
        progressBar.setVisible(true);
        timer.restart();
        }

        if(e.getSource()==btnProceed)
        {
            SRC_Main load = new SRC_Main();

              load.setVisible(true);
             this.dispose();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        WelcomeSRC obj = new WelcomeSRC();  
    }

}
```

CarsRec class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CarsRec
{
    private String carID="";
    private String Name="";
    private String Liter="";
    private String Transm="";
    private String Year="";
    private String Mileage="";
    private String ModComp="";
    private String ModStage="";
    private String Perform="";
    private String Price="";
    private String CusName="";
    private String CusEmail="";

    public CarsRec(){}

    public CarsRec(String cID ,String N ,String L ,String TR ,String Y ,String M,String MDC ,String MDS ,String PF ,String PR,String CSN ,String CSE) 
    {
        carID=cID;
        Name=N;
        Liter=L;
        Transm=TR;
        Year=Y;
        Mileage=M;
        ModComp=MDC;
        ModStage=MDS;
        Perform=PF;
        Price=PR;
        CusName=CSN;
        CusEmail=CSE;
    }
    //Accessor methods
    public String getCarID()
    { return carID;}
    public String getName()
    { return Name;}
    public String getLiter()
    { return Liter;}
    public String getTrans()
    { return Transm;}
    public String getYear()
    { return Year;}
    public String getMileage()
    { return Mileage;}
    public String getModComp()
    { return ModComp;}
    public String getModStage()
    { return ModStage;}
    public String getPerformance()
    { return Perform;}
    public String getPrice()
    { return Price;}
    public String getCusName()
    { return CusName;}
    public String getCusEmail()
    { return CusEmail;}

}
```

Comment: You will need to add some code to your post, mostly likely from SRC_Main.actionPerformed.

Comment: Apologies Chris, I have added the code.

Comment: I added the entire code so as to give you detailed look at it,in case there might be logic errors earlier in the code

Comment: 1) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556) 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I will read them,I really appreciate the feedback and I would love some more suggestions on possible correction or solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See line no. 289 ->`if(i<carPathImg.length)`

The carPathImg contains 6 strings(image path), so length 6.

I think your input file `"CarRecords.txt"` doesn't contain 6 lines with 12 words separated by #. Check your input file.

Length of `carPathImg` and `arrMasterRec` must be same.

You need to add below code in `WelcomeSRC.java` for `if(e.getSource()==btnProceed)`

```
SRC_Main load =new SRC_Main();
load.OpenFile();
CarsRec[] arrMRecords=load.ReadFile();
load.setCarRecs(arrMRecords); 
load.setVisible(true);
this.dispose();
```

This error is for one of the variables you are passing is null, but the code tries to use it like it is not.

I run the code, it runs good now without error and press `next` and `previous`  button as many time as user want. There is no error.

Comment: Hi David that didn't work and printing each element resulted in the same error. I'm also confused about the fact that the SRC_Main frame runs perfectly if I run the frame itself but if I run the Welcome Frame and click the button to go to the SRC Main, then only does it throw errors...it's as if the SRC Main doesn't run the methods to populate the arrayMasterRec

Comment: Can you give me the whole project via dropbox, then I will try to see it . @Gordon

Comment: It's basically those two jframes i will also add the welcome frame code

Comment: Where is your CarsRec class? @Gordon.exe

Comment: Really sorry David, I've added the CarsRec class

Comment: @Gordon.exe, see the answer section. I added some things there. Hope it will help. I test your code. I ran without error.

Comment: hi David I've tried that now and I still seem to get the error, could you provide your portion of code that you changed so I can check mine?

Comment: does your input file "CarRecords.txt" contain 6 lines with 12 words separated by # ? Check your input file. @Gordon.exe

Comment: yes there is , 6lines with 12 words separated  by #

Comment: chcek this two link :
http://ideone.com/Itvwzt
http://ideone.com/cB6cXl
and check the answer (edited) @Gordon.exe

Comment: Yes! Finally, That was so silly of me. David Thank you for all your help, I really appreciate it. I'm new here so how do I declare this thread as answered and is there a recommendation function so I can tell the community of how helpful and patient you've been with me? Really thankful.

Comment: Welcome. If the answer helps you, then accept the answer by clicking the left side green tick. @Gordon.exe

Comment: Done! Thanks once again David